# what is app_uuid? heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, python-requests

I `requests.get` from https://api.heroku.com/accounts/user_id/actions/get-quota and the result should be account quota and used app hours, but there is a strange value in it called `app_uuid`

```
{'quota_used': 852710, 'force_idle_until': None, 'apps': [{'quota_used': 512115, 'app_uuid': '637f6377-4abe-4156-8f65-a01c12bd0e07'}, {'quota_used': 340595, 'app_uuid': 'e898dee7-09fa-46ae-97de-220bcd732bd4'}], 'account_uuid': 'dd949884-b0c4-4f09-8947-c966a03660e7', 'account_quota': 3600000}
```

I tried to check and made a call with `heroku.app(app_uuid)` but the result is 404

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.heroku.com/apps/e898dee7-09fa-46ae-97de-220bcd732bd4
```

So where do I get those `app_uuid` except from quota result, I want to match with the app name and used quota for my scripts, thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the app_uuid is app_id itself, but the result from `request.get` is app that is deleted, because app that haven't use any usage it doesn't get write in result.